# how to get two items on one row when using flow grow and row wrap without using line breaks?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have spend hours trying to figure out why two divs will only stay on the same row using flex box when line breaks are added in html in paragraph within the header class or set width for being having to be defined what I want is for portrait div to have set width of 300px and bio to size to fill to remaining size avialble .

CSS

```
.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between; }

.bio {
  order: 1;
  flex-grow: 1; }

.bio p {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.portrait {
  order: 2;
  width: 300px; }

.portrait img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 30px solid white; }
```

HTML

```
  <div class="intro">
      <div class="portrait">
        <img src="assets/img/me.jpg" alt="Nicola Sansom">
      </div>
      <div class="bio">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Content</p>
           <div class="well-versed">
           <b>1 Col</b>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you want it to stay in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?
I think I dont understand 100% your question

```css
.intro {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-flow: row wrap;*/
  align-items: center;
 /* justify-content: space-between;*/ }

.bio {
  width:100%;
  background-color:pink;
  order: 1;
  /*flex-grow: 1; */}

.bio p {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.portrait {
 order: 2;
  width: 300px; }

.portrait img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 30px solid white; }
```

```html
 <div class="intro">
      <div class="portrait">
        <img src="assets/img/me.jpg" alt="Nicola Sansom">
      </div>
      <div class="bio">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Content</p>
           <div class="well-versed">
           <b>1 Col</b>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```